# How to sync a Visual Studio project across computers

Tags: visual-studio

I need to sync a local Visual Studio solution across to my laptop so I can continue to work on it while travelling. At the moment I get a working copy of the solution from TFS (online version), work on it at my PC and when needed I manually copy it to my laptop.

On my PC I have the SkyDrive client installed which syncs with my SkyDrive account. I have created a temporary VS solution and stored it inside of the local SkyDrive folder. As I work on it the changes are synced to SkyDrive and then my laptop. There is obviously a fair bit of synching if I build the solution a lot, but overall it does what I was hoping.

This seems like a workable idea, but I was wondering if anyone else has tried this approach and if there are potential problems with it? Is it a practical idea?

One other possible idea is Shelve Sets?

I am using Windows 8 Pro and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Can you not access your TFS installation online?

Comment: I can, yes. But the problem is I can be working at my PC, but then need to travel to another site and I need to take the what I've been working on at my PC with me. I would then be able to continue my work and then either sync back with my PC later or check-in directly to TFS.

Comment: Then branch before you start working and checkin the branch.

Comment: If you have access to shelve sets then what is wrong with checking in on your pc and then getting the latest version on your laptop? You then check back in on the laptop when finished and get the latest version on the pc. Simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like Shelvesets are the answer. From my PC and I shelve my changes, go to my laptop, get the shelveset, work on it and then put it back or check it in. This seems like a much cleaner and easier way then going down the SkyDrive route.